# Replace Method in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, javascript-objects, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I want to replace the text coming in my string.The Response is coming from the service and I am getting the response with `~` expression.

I want to replace the `~` expression with `"\n"` so that the text can come in next line.

I tried replace method but it is not working. How can I achieve this?

Also I am using the code below:

```
self.email = response.invocationResult.email.replace(/~/g ,  " \n ");
```

Comment: The code you've posted [works perfectly fine](http://jsfiddle.net/L5h9po6f/). Please include a full (but minimal) repro for your situation.

Comment: Actually it is replacing everything but it is not replacing with \n..i.e. it is not coming in next line in application.....

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "*it is not coming in next line*"? If you look at my example, that uses your *exact* code, each e-mail address is placed on its own line, prepended with a space as per your regex. So again, please update your question and add a full repro.

Comment: (Just checking, you didn't mean to use `<br>` instead of `\n`, did you?)

Comment: Just for fun, an alternative to `str.replace` in this example: `str.split('~').join('<br>')`

Comment: If he is using the <br /> in the string the text binding is bound to he would have to use .html(string) instead of .text(string)